# How to fix damaged rear suspension arm on 2001 Honda Accord

Tags: honda, suspension, accord

I have a 2001 Honda Accord LX.  While removing my old sway bar links with an angle grinder, I accidentaly cut into a rear suspension arm.  The cut looks worse in real life than in pictures, and I would estimate that it is about 1/8" - 3/16" deep.  My question is: Should I replace the arm or is the cut not a big problem?  I included pics of the actual cut and one stock pic of the arm I'm refering to.  Thanks.
[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering what this rod actually does, it probably wouldn't matter. It helps align the wheel correctly and keeps it spaced from the car. The main part of the suspension here which does any work is the strut and spring assembly. The little nick you have on it probably would not amount to much.

That said, the nick on there does create a stress riser, which is a place where stress is concentrated. This can create a spot where a crack can form if enough stress occurs there. Since you've also cut away any type of corrosion resistance, you're also going to see rust start to form here. This is an easy fix, though, as a shot of spray paint should protect it well enough.

One other thing to consider. If you truly are worried about it, this piece (lower rear rearward control arm) is relatively inexpensive and easily replaced. Just replace it and call it a day. I'm sure it being over 20 years old, the bushings are probably not in perfect shape, so replacement might be a good thing.